# How are cleft sentences different from normal structures

Tags: syntax

I am always curious about ***it-cleft*** sentences. How do you draw trees using binary branches and how is it different from normal structures: "It is .... that...."

Is the difference interpreted in the semantics rather than the tree? Or it could be explained in the tree?

Compare these two sentences:

(1) It was he that saw Mary. (not she)

(2) It was him that saw Mary. (not her)

How do we analyze the difference between these two sentences then?

This is a picture from Wikipedia

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence

[image]

Comment: Both your examples are OK, though the one with "he" is much more formal. The tree diagrams would be identical. I very much dislike the kind of diagram you provide. It tells us nothing about the constituent structure of the clause or the function of each constituent.

Comment: @BillJ Same here. I don't enjoy the tree either.  So I am just wondering how the case of the pronoun is assigned in the tree.

Comment: It doesn't have to be assigned a case. In a decent tree it would be assigned two labels, a function label (Predicative Complement) ) and a category (POS) label (NP).

Comment: @AlecB I am not really getting BillJ's explanation about case. I am assuming that it is a prescriptive rule concerning (1). I am not sure if I get it right.

Comment: @BillJ could you please explain more about category labels and function labels? I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: @Xia.Yili You mentioned "case" in your first comment, which I took to be a reference to the contrasting inflectional case of nominative "he" and accusative "him" in your examples, which you asked about in your question. Every constituent in a clause is given a function label and a category label. As I said in my second comment, the pronouns "he/him" would be assigned two labels: function = Predicative Complement, category (POS) = (NP).

Comment: Xia and @AlexB. There's a substantial problem with the tree. The problem is that according the tree, "John that Mary saw" is a constituent. However, it isn't "John" and the relative clause are two completely different constituents (part of the reason for considering the structure 'cleft' in two). This is quite different therefore from when the relative clause is a modifier within the DP/NP.

Comment: The comments above are a great example why we shouldn’t be discussing trees unless a specific theory the OP is interested in is explicitly mentioned.

Comment: Xia, there are lots of ways of doing syntax, hence my question, *which theory of syntax did you have in mind?* That is why you don’t understand what BillJ is saying here, because he likes CGEL a lot and not Adger or  Pesetsky. In Government and Binding we have the case filter, in the MP it’s all about feature checking.

Comment: @Araucaria-him you're right of course, I didn't look at the tree carefully enough. John that Mary saw is a not a constituent, so it should be slightly revised. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting exchange and commentary here! The tree is indeed bad. The string _John that Mary saw_ is shown as a constituent, which it clearly shouldn't be based on various tests for constituents (proform substitution, answer fragments, clefting itself). The problem, though, is one that afflicts much of mainstream syntactic theory, namely all those theories that assume strict binarity of branching. N-ary branching is necessary if one intends to produce a plausible rendition of the constituent structure of cleft sentences and many other types of sentences.

Comment: I've posted a CGEL-type tree, which may be of help.

Comment: How to diagram cleft sentences using binary branching, see for instance Fig 9 (p.19) in Han and Hedberg http://www.sfu.ca/~hedberg/itcleft-js-edited.pdf

Comment: @Alex B. Han and Hedberg's tree analyses of cleft sentences are no more plausible (and much more complex) than the Wikipedia tree above in the question. They also show the focus and the cleft clause forming a constituent, although they call this constituent a CopP or an FP rather than a DP.

Comment: @AlexB. I don't think invoking arcane theoretical concepts and formalisms is helpful

Comment: @BillJ well, I’m not endorsing any theory here. However, if the OP is asking a question couched in a particular framework (clearly Government and Binding or less likely the MP), I don’t think it’s the best course of action to start a discussion about how cleft sentences can be analyzed by different syntacticians. Incidentally the question about Case assignment (capital C, to make it less ambiguous for those who are not in the know) still stands.

Comment: @TimOsborne but I’m not endorsing it or not condoning it, I just used it as an example. If a student approaches you with a minor question about generative syntax, will you start a long spiel about how wrong it is or should you try to answer the question?  What do you think?

Comment: @AlexB. I am thinking about mainstream syntax "GB" but also I am open to other fields as well. Yes I found that "John that Mary saw" is not a constituent.

Comment: @Xia.Yili I’m glad you made it clear now - now that you’ve indicated your interest in the other theories too

Comment: @AlexB Could you please explain it in the framework of Government and Binding theory if it is possible? I have found that tree from Wikipedia is terrible and how would you revise it? Plus I don't quite endorse the tree you have mentioned though because they are too many extra levels.

Comment: @Alex B. Understood. Point well made.

Comment: @Xia.Yili I might, it will take me some time though. You see, when I was in grad school, a decade ago, we studied GBT for a year, but only in the historical context, i.e. how things *were*. The MP was all the rage already then. So I'd have to dust off the books and see how cleft sentences were analyzed back then. Of course I encourage everyone to do the same. I'm sure there are more knowledgable folks here, e.g. Tim Osborne is def one of them.

Comment: @AlexB.Thanks for taking the time to check the old knowledge here. The tree on MP is rather clear to me to see how the syntax works. I am getting it better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

For the sake of simplicity, I have treated "that" as a relative pronoun. Strictly speaking, it's actually a subordinator.

Comment: The answer is terribly brief; it's simply a tree with no explanation. And its correctness is debatable because it shows _was John_ as a constituent. What evidence is there that _was John_ should be viewed as a constituent? Tests for constituents do not identify _was John_ as a constituent.

Comment: Thanks, @BillJ although I am not quite familiar with the framework you have provided. It strikes me very much that there are two clauses (one is head clause and the other is the dependent clause.) I have found it very different and I am curious about the relatively flat structures compared to other frameworks, i.e., Government and Binding Theory.

Comment: What evidence is there _was John_ is a constituent? That string cannot be questioned, it cannot be elided, it cannot be replaced by a proform substitute. Your tree is still too layered. It needs to be yet flatter in such a manner that _John_ and _that Mary saw_ are constituents, but not _John that Mary saw_ and not _was John_.

Comment: @TimOsborne In any clause, the subject and predicate are the immediate constituents. I don't see any reason why the head clause here should be any different.

Comment: @Xia.Yili The tree is based on standard descriptive grammar.  In an _it_-cleft construction the foregrounded element (here, "John") functions as predicative complement to "be", while the backgrounded part is expressed in a relative clause (the 'dependent' clause), with the foregrounded element as antecedent for the relativised element. The relative clause does not form a constituent with its antecedent but appears in extranuclear position at the end of the clause. I think the tree shows that structure clearly.

Comment: The predicate of an it-cleft sentence likely does not include the focus, but rather the focus is most certainly the/an argument of the predicate.  In a sentence such as It is _John that is happy_, the property of being happy is being predicated of _John_, making _John_ "the subject" in the relevant sense.

Comment: Thanks, BillJ for clarifying for me! I remember I study the immediate constituents before when I was an undergraduate. Now I can recall what I have studied and the tree does make sense to me now although I don't use this framework.

Answer (score 1):

In the MP, omitting some irrelevant details, one way of doing it is this (based on [Belletti 2009](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/mono/10.4324/9780203887134/structures-strategies-adriana-belletti?refId=1089ff2a-8092-4bde-a83f-5b471476404b&context=ubx) and [Haegeman et al. 2015](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/283730146_The_Syntax_of_It-clefts_and_the_Left_Periphery_of_the_Clause)):

[image: ![enter image description here]

see section 2.1. The Middlefield analysis for further details in Haegeman, Liliane, André Meinunger, and Aleksandra Vercauteren, 'The Syntax of It-clefts and the Left Periphery of the Clause', Beyond Functional Sequence: The Cartography of Syntactic Structures, Volume 10, Oxford Studies in Comparative Syntax (New York, 2015)

If you're familiar with the basics of the MP, it should be pretty clear to you (e.g. vP, strikethrough for deleted copies etc.), nothing unusual there. It is still binary branching - consistent with the theory - and it captures the constituency tests pretty well too. I tried to use the standard MP notation found e.g. in [Adger 2003](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/core-syntax-9780199243709?cc=us&lang=en&)

Comment: The answer stays within the parameters set out in the question insofar as strict binarity of  branching should be maintained. In this regard, it is good. The answer also claims, however, that the analysis "captures the constituency tests pretty well". I disagree. It actually does worse in this area than the Wikipedia tree in the question.

Comment: The analysis has the same problem as that Wikipedia tree: it shows _John that Mary saw_ as a constituent. Furthermore, it also shows _It was_ as a constituent. Neither of those strings is verifiable as a constituent by diagnostics for sentence structure. The analysis has to allow n-ary branching if it is going to capture what tests for constituents reveal. An analysis is needed that shows _John_ and _that Mary saw_ as constituents, and _It was_, _was John_, and _John that Mary saw_ as non-constituents.

Comment: A phrase structure analysis that accomplishes the job is as follows: _[It [was [John] [that Mary saw]]]_. Note, though, that even this analysis has a weakness: it shows _was John that Mary saw_ as a constituent despite the fact that there is no evidence supporting that string as a constituent (Note that BillJ's tree does not have this weakness). In my view, then, the best phrase structure analysis of the sentence would be as follows: _[[it] [was] [John] [that Mary saw]]_. The structure is indeed hence quite flat.

Comment: Thanks for your time @AlexB this tree is much easier to understand compared to the former complex tree. It is interesting to see that "John" is moved from the complement of "saw" to spec FocP.

Comment: @TimOsborne I agree with you when you say that "was John that Mary saw" is not a constituent. To quote Huddleston: "A major distinguishing feature of the _it_-cleft construction is that the relative clause does not form a constituent with its antecedent". Hence the relative clause in my tree being shown as a dependent clause, but not a modifying one, reflects that observation.

Comment: Constructions in the information packaging domain, like clefts etc, is that they don't lend themselves to bracketing, or diagrams like the OP's You simply have to employ the traditional tree diagram. Btw, thanks for the downvote!

Comment: @BillJ I’m afraid you didn’t understand the notation here, was John that Mary saw is **not** a constituent.

Comment: @TimOsborne it’s always good to know what other linguists think, thanks! I knew it would turn into a discussion whose tree is flatter - hence my strong reluctance to post - but I just wanted to help the OP, nothing else.

Comment: I misread Tim's comment, sorry. But I stick with my last comment. Endless arguments about arcane theoretical concepts get us nowhere, which is why I think the basic tree is the best way of illustrating the constituents.

Comment: @BillJ fair enough, and I'm sorry if you took the exchange here somewhat personally, whose theory could be better. I just tried to answer the question about generative syntax using generative syntax, nothing more.

Comment: @TimOsborne I intentionally simplified my analysis here - and that is why there's no tree here either - It was is not a constituent here. In the MP there's v-to-T raising (see e.g. Adger 2003: 184), so "It was" doesn't form a constituent.

Comment: OK. Perhaps a tree would have been better, then. And I myself would be interested to see/learn which analysis Alex B prefers.